# Using Object.values() in Stackblitz Angular Project

Tags: angular, typescript, stackblitz

In [this stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/object-method) we can use `Object.values()`.

I'm trying to use it in [this Angular project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s3t1f7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) and it throws:

> Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.

I know that in general typescript projects via have to say that it's for a ES2017 environment specifically in TSConfig.  Is there some setting in Stackblitz that can be flipped for this?

IIUC Angular should get `Object.values` from [CoreJS](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/110).

Comment: I think you can manually add in your `tsconfig.json` at the `.angular-cli.json` level.

Comment: It's `"lib": ["es2017"]` `in `tsconfig.json`, but I don't see it in `.angular-cli.json` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that to fix that problem you can simply install typescript in stackblitz project dependencies. Just simply write:

```
npm i typescript
```

I had exacly the same error and now I have got fully working intellisense. Hope it helps!

Check out on this project:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-validation-errors