# Can Object.values() be used in Angular Projects?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-2017

It appears [it does not work in Stackblitz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52372242/using-object-values-in-stackblitz-angular-project), but can `Object.values()` be used in general in Angular projects?

IIUC Angular includes [CoreJS](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/110) and the purpose of it is to allow things like `Object.values()` to be available across all browsers?

Comment: Object.values is still experimental and so you need to change your lib array in tsconfig

Comment: I amended the question a bit.  In light of that is the tsconfig `lib: "es2017"` change still necessary?

Comment: you may want to try esnext?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for typescript to recognize `Object.values`, the developer should add to tsconfig.json `compilerOptions: {lib: ["esnext"]}`. Stackblitz simply does not have this setting.

Angular absolutely can utilize this feature, because it is [well supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#Browser_compatibility) by modern browsers (except old IE, as always)

Comment: Yes Stackblitz is slightly bipolar in this scenario.  It supports it with general typescript, but not with angular ...

Comment: It is maybe because IIRC angular has pretty complex system of tsconfig.json files (there are few of them, one root and several extending children), and complex build flow. P.S. Thanks for selecting my answer as best.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it - I assume polyfills are covered by CoreJS in general right?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with CoreJS, and didn't encounter it anywhere while working on Angular or Typescript projects. I can just tell you that `Object.values` as well as many new methods like `entries` is ok to use (even without any polyfills), unless supporting IE is a strong business requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which browser you're targetting. It won't work as such in non-supported browsers. You can find a list of Supporting Browsers [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#Browser_compatibility)

That being said, you can still use it in Older Browsers by using Polyfills. You can find these polyfills [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#Polyfill).

Polyfills are used in place of JS that is not available as a part of a Browser. If `lib` from `tsconfig` is used, it is going to compile/transpile the TypeScript into a suitable version of JavaScript specified in the `lib` array. So adding `lib: "es2017"` to `tsconfig` would mean it won't work on browsers that don't implicitly support ES2017.

But adding a Polyfill instead would mean that it would also work on browsers that don't support this script.

Comment: I amended the question a bit.  In light of that (CoreJS) is the tsconfig `lib: "es2017"` change still necessary / Do I understand the purpose of CoreJS correctly - I thought that was the polyfill?

Comment: From what I understand, Polyfills are used in place of JS that is not available as a part of a Browser. If `lib` from `tsconfig` is used, it is going to `compile`/`transpile` the typescript into a suitable version of JavaScript specified in the `lib` array. So adding `lib: "es2017"` to `tsconfig` would mean it won't work on browsers that don't implicitly supoort ES2017.

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  My original understanding though was that Angular includes CoreJS such that we don't have to worry about the polyfill at all, so I'm curious as to whether we actually need to do something to get `Object.values()` to work.  It seems all Angular projects should just set `lib:esnext` by default, since Angular bakes it in via CoreJS?